# Как внутри цикла wordpress поместить изображение?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, циклы, изображения

Есть стандартный цикл на wordpress. Интересует, как внутри стандартного цикла анонсов (ограничение в 7 статей)

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<li> 
  <span class="li--span"><span class="li--span--category"><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></span></span>   
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="li--a">                                        
    <span class="little_content"><?php the_title(); ?></span>   
  </a>                                
</li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Вывести картинку после 4 анонса, т.е. должны быть 4 записи- картинка - еще 3 записи после

```
<a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/img/advertisement.jpg" width="300" height="500" title="Перейти на сайт рекламодателя" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто, вам надо проверять какой по счёту пост и вставлять вашу картинку:

```
  <?php
    $counter = 0;
     if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <li> 
          <span class="li--span"><span class="li--span--category"><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></span></span>   
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="li--a">                                        
            <span class="little_content"><?php the_title(); ?></span>   
          </a>                                
        </li>

    <?php if ($counter % 4 == 0) {?>
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/img/advertisement.jpg" width="300" height="500" title="Перейти на сайт рекламодателя" /></a>
    <?php } ?>

        <?php
    $counter++;  
     endwhile; ?>
```